# Getting Enum key based on value retrieved from mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My enum is as follows -

```
enum MyEnum 
{
    Login,//(1),
    Password,//(2),
    OTP,//(3),
    Settings,//(4),
    ButtonClicked,//(5)
    //.....and so on.
}
```

The data I receive is as follows -

```
{ "_id" : 1, "count" : 558 }
{ "_id" : 3, "count" : 554 }
{ "_id" : 2, "count" : 554 }
....
```

Now i want to print it as

```
{ "_id" : "Login", "count" : 558 }
{ "_id" : "OTP", "count" : 554 }
{ "_id" : "Password", "count" : 554 }
```

This is to be done in MongoDB. I'm fairly new to the tech and I would really like some help with this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by print? Print on mongo shell, print using your specific driver?

Comment: Print as in getting this result through a query .

Comment: What are you using? JS, C#, Java, Python?

Comment: What do you mean by using here?

Comment: If you are trying to print the results on your mongo shell there is an answer, if you are using a language like JS, C#, Java or Python the answer is different since the driver provided for that language will probably take care of mapping enums

Comment: I want to print them on mongo shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const myEnum = {
    1: 'Login',//(1),
    2: 'Password',//(2),
    3: 'OTP',//(3),
    4: 'Settings',//(4),
    5: 'ButtonClicked',//(5)
    //.....and so on.
}
const res = [ { "_id" : "1", "count" : 558 },
{ "_id" : "2", "count" : 554 },
{ "_id" : "3", "count" : 554 }];

const result = res.map((el) => {
  el._id = myEnum[el._id];
  return el;
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] is the result obtained from this.

Comment: try to stringify the objects